# How to get a message from a redirect in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

return Redirect::to('KSMschema')->with('message', $HeadNr)->withErrors($v);
    }
I have a redirect message called 'message'. How do i display this message in my view?

## Hello,

This does not work. It only seems to work if you make a View.

I can't find anything in the laravel documentaion about displaying messages in a view from a Redirect.
http://laravel.com/docs/responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirected messages come back stored in the Session, If you do:

```
Redirect::to('KSMschema')->with('message', $HeadNr);
```

You have to

```
echo Session::get('message);
```